# Get SQLite Table Data into HTML Table

Tags: php, html, sqlite, html-table

I have an SQLite database and using PHP to serve up and interact the data with.

I am trying to build an HTML table with for each SQLite table columns as the HTML Table Columns and then for each row in the SQLite table render as a for each row in the HTML table.

**Issue is that each** sql row data is only rendered into one html table row (with current code) (should be for each row) question would be how I go about getting the sql row data into array for looping through to render html table rows.

Currently I have;

**PHP get the SQL Columns into the HTML table & SQl Row data(foreach) into HTML Table Rows (foreach)**

```
//get table count
$countTable = $dbConnect->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ".$table['name']."");

if($countTable){

//data exists, do work
//new query to get table data
$query = $dbConnect->query("SELECT * FROM ".$table['name']." ORDER BY id DESC");

//init arrays
$dataColumns = array();
$dataRows = array();

while($row = $query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{


   //add columns to array, checking if value exists
   foreach($row as $key => $value)
   {

       if(in_array(''.$key.'', $dataColumns)){

          //column already in array, dont add again.

       }else{

            //column not in array, add it.
            $dataColumns[]=array(
                'column'=>$key
            );  

        }

        //while in this foreach do I add the row values to an array or do it again outside this loop?

        //below does not work, only adds to the one array item and renders one HTML Table row with multiple SQL Table row values
        $dataRows[]=array(
            'row_item'=>$row[''.$row.'']
        );


    }

   }

   //build HTML table

   echo '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table"><thead><tr>';

   //build columns from array... works
   foreach($dataColumns as $dataColumn){
        echo '<th>'.$dataColumn['column'].'</th>';
    }

    //close table column headers 7 start HTML table body...
    echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

    //Issue is here, how do I get the each row (value is either null or not null) to

    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($dataRows as $dataRow){
        echo '<td>'.$dataRow['row_item'].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';


    //close table body & table...
    echo '</tbody></table></div>';


}else{

//table has no data
echo 'no data in the selected table';

}
```

Comment: issue & question. Issue is that each sql row data is only rendered into one html table row (with current code) (should be for each row) question would be how I go about getting the sql row data into array for looping through to render html table rows.

Comment: Your while loop (`while($row = $query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))`) should end just before the comment ' //build HTML table'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rewrote this to do it all in one loop like this.

```pl
$firstRow = true;
echo '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">';
while ($row = $query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    if ($firstRow) {
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr></thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';
        $firstRow = false;
    }

    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table></div>';
```

You might find it clearer to read? It also avoids building an array of all the dataRows in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
$dataRows[]=array(
    'row_item'=>$row[''.$row.'']
);
```

with

```
$dataRows[]=$row;
```

Put this line at first line inside your while loop (or general outside the foreach loop over your columns), because adding a row is not connected analyzing your columns.

Then, in your output foreach, you should find the rows with all columns selected from your database query inside `$dataRow` (here symbolized with column1, column2, …):

```
echo '<tr>';
foreach($dataRows as $dataRow){
    echo '<td>'.$dataRow['column1'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$dataRow['column2'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$dataRow['column3'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$dataRow['column4'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$dataRow['column5'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$dataRow['column6'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$dataRow['column7'].'</td>';
    // etc.
}
echo '</tr>';
```

After all your code should look like this (a bit simplified):

```
$query = $dbConnect->query("SELECT * FROM ".$table['name']." ORDER BY id DESC");

$dataColumns = array();
$dataRows = array();

while ($row = $query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    $dataRows[] = $row;

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        //Bilding $dataColumns, see Question
    }
}

echo '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table"><thead><tr>';

foreach ($dataColumns as $dataColumn) {
    echo '<th>'.$dataColumn['column'].'</th>';
}

echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

echo '<tr>';
foreach ($dataRows as $dataRow) {
    foreach ($dataRow as $columnName => $columnValue) {
        echo '<td>'.$columnValue.'</td>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';

echo '</tbody></table></div>';
```

Comment: Essentially works but only shows one row even though I know I have multiple rows in the table. Also want to echo each column row value without using(assuming) I know the column name $dataRow['the column name'] ...

Comment: You'll need a second foreach: `foreach($dataRow as $key => $value){echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';}`

Comment: removed the $dataRows = array(); allowed me to get each row data but still need to get the row column value without knowing the column name in $dataRow['column1'];

Comment: hm, that doesn't make sense. Now you shoud get a notice, that $dataRows is not defined while trying to add the database rows. Did you place `$dataRows[]=$row;` in the beginning of your while loop?

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to akrys**

in the while loop, but outside the foreach column loop;

```
 //$dataRows = array();
 $dataRows[]=$row;
```

and in the building of the HTML Table;

```
 foreach($dataRows as $dataRow){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($dataRow as $key => $value){echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';}
    echo '</tr>';
}
```